# How to get list of unanswered question for all interesting tags at once?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

It's probably being new here, but I can't seem to filter unanswered questions by all of me "interested" tags at once.  Instead I need to filter them tag by tag, one at a time.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Unanswered -> my tags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags)

Comment: That only displays questions with no upvoted answers.

Comment: Is there any way to have these sorted by newest? As I've had this saved as my homepage for a few days to answer new questions each day but the same questions always show in the same (seemingly random order)

Comment: That's only per-site, isn't it?