# Is the "filtered questions" unanswered list complete?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, tag-watching, tag-filters

I regularly look for [old unanswered questions in my feed](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116580/mediawiki?pagesize=50&page=2) for a topic I care about so that I can go answer where the rest of the community failed to produce an answer in months. (A last resort responder.)

In looking questions older than six months at StackOverflow, I noticed some unanswered questions which I don't remember seeing in the filtered list. In fact, the filtered list only goes back to 2014-09-18 as of now, which seems rather suspicious as there's plenty of ancient questions. In fact, [statistics for one of the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mediawiki/topusers) count some 500 unanswered questions, but the tag filter shows only 100.

Is the list complete? Is there any way to get to the bottom of the list?

Comment: How comes there's no tag for the stackexchange.com/filters/ functionality?

Comment: There is, I've added it now.

Comment: Off topic, but why exactly did you suggest [this totally useless tag edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38928)? Trying to test edit ban?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, thanks for the tag. I added that tag because together with [unanswered-questions] it helped me find [another related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73900/248268)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not complete: you can get only 100 results.

To get more questions to the bottom of the queue, you can

- split the filter in smaller filters;
- downvote bad questions in the hope they get [autodeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006);
- answer some of the shown questions, to make room and get some older unanswered questions raise into the first 100.

Yes, it's irritating!

Comment: Example searches to find autodeletable stuff: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/327229/questions-of-a-specific-tag-that-tend-towards-auto-deletion, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmediawiki%5D+or+%5Bmediawiki-api%5D+or+%5Bmediawiki-extensions%5D+or+%5Bwikipedia-api%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+created%3A..1y